# Linking several programs with CMake

Tags: c, linker, cmake

I have three programs which computes a quantity S in serial code, and in parallel using MPI and OpenMP. All programs needs the same header file utils.h. Somehow, after running cmake .., I need to run make twice to compile the program correctly as the first run results in linking errors (the standard libraries seems not to be linked). Any ideas why this is the case?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(compute_S)

find_package(MPI)
enable_language(C)

include_directories(${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-std=c99")
add_executable(compute_S compute_S.c utils.h)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-std=c99")
add_executable(compute_S_MPI compute_S_MPI.c utils.h)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-std=c99 -fopenmp")
add_executable(compute_S_OpenMP compute_S_OpenMP.c utils.h)

target_link_libraries(compute_S ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(compute_S_MPI ${MPI_C_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(compute_S_OpenMP ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

You can reproduce the error by running the following

```
mkdir test 
cd test 
git clone https://github.com/Zetison/exerciseSet4 
cd exerciseSet4 
cmake . 
make
```

Comment: What is `catkin_LIBRARIES`?

Comment: It is explained here: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt (search for Catkin_LIBRARIES)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the example at https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-June/045037.html which shows how to link MPI. The module FindMPI.cmake creates the following variables:

- `MPI_INCLUDE_PATH` : the include search path
- `MPI_LIBRARIES`: the name of the mi library.
- `MPI_COMPILE_FLAGS` and `MPI_LINK_FLAGS`: flags to compile and link.

Similarly, the [FindOpenMP.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindOpenMP.cmake) module creates the variables  `OpenMP_C_FLAGS`, `OpenMP_Fortran_FLAGS` and `OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS` which correspond to `MPI_LINK_FLAGS`. Indeed, it can resume to `-fopenmp`.

Could you try the following `CMakeLists.txt` by typing `cmake .` then `make` ?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(compute_S)

find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
enable_language(C)

include_directories(${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-std=c99")
add_executable(compute_S compute_S.c utils.h)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-std=c99")
add_executable(compute_S_MPI compute_S_MPI.c utils.h)
# https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-June/045037.html
target_link_libraries(compute_S_MPI ${MPI_LIBRARIES})

if(MPI_COMPILE_FLAGS)
  set_target_properties(compute_S_MPI PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_FLAGS "${MPI_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
endif()

if(MPI_LINK_FLAGS)
  set_target_properties(compute_S_MPI PROPERTIES
    LINK_FLAGS "${MPI_LINK_FLAGS}")
endif()

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-std=c99")
add_executable(compute_S_OpenMP compute_S_OpenMP.c utils.h)

# https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindOpenMP.html
#message(${OpenMP_C_FLAGS})
if(OpenMP_C_FLAGS)
  set_target_properties(compute_S_OpenMP PROPERTIES
    LINK_FLAGS "${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
endif()

target_link_libraries(compute_S ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(compute_S_MPI ${MPI_C_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(compute_S_OpenMP ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: The same error occur. I have updated the description such that one can reproduce the error.

Comment: @user2978680 I managed to compile your program with the modified CMakeLists.txt. I got warnings, because the function `fabs()` is called in `utils.h`. Could you try to add `#include <math.h>` in `utils.h` and `target_link_libraries(compute_S ${catkin_LIBRARIES} m)
target_link_libraries(compute_S_MPI ${MPI_C_LIBRARIES} m)
target_link_libraries(compute_S_OpenMP ${catkin_LIBRARIES} m)` in the CMakeLists.txt? Hence, the math library will be included and linked. Remove CMakeCache.txt before running cmake again. If it does not solve your problem,  I can't move this rock, and I'll remove my answer !

Comment: Moreover, the variable `${catkin_LIBRARIES}` is not set if `find_package(catkin REQUIRED)` is not added at the begining of the CMakeLists.txt. You can add `message(${catkin_LIBRARIES})` to check that the variable is set.

Comment: How embarrassing, I must have removed the inclusion of the math library at some point. Thanks for help!! :)

Comment: @user2978680 :you're welcome ! Don't feel embarrassed !